# How to center align pagination in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to center align pagination in bootstrap 4? I place the code, and pagination is pressed to the left all the time, but it needs to be centered. I applied class `text-center` to the parent element, it also did not help, although the text aligns, but for some reason it does not work with pagination.

```
<div class="text-center">
     {{$posts->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4')}}
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding class "mx-auto"

Answer (score -1):

You question definitely lacks detail but my guess is add 'd-block' to that div or 'mx-auto'